# Angular ui-select box disable auto direction up

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a  box that is auto changing the direction based on screen size. The way it does this is adding a "direction-up" class to the directive. Anyway I can disable this behavior?

**EDIT:**

Answer below was great and concise, please do note you need angular-ui-select >= 0.13.0 for the answer below to work.

Comment: Please provide us with some code, otherwise it's hard to guess what the problem might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force it to always open down by adding the `position="down"` attribute to the `ui-select-choices` element as follows:

```
<ui-select-choices position="down">
...
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: Pleased to have been of assistance

Comment: Just want to add one thing, I was on angular-ui-select 0.12.0 and the position tag was not supported. I had to upgrade to 0.13.0 (latest supported version for the position tag).